# unmet dependencies (held broken packages) can't install php5-gd

Tags: php, apt, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and trying to install php5-gd php_extension, but getting the following error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    php5-gd : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.11) but 5.5.14+dfsg-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed

I'm sure it's a problem mixing repositories, but I can't pinpoint the problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's my current sources:

```
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
```

Comment: Try to remove any external repos. Ubuntu 14.04.3 [repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php5-gd) has 5.5.9 and not 5.5.14

Comment: Maybe not all, as @Panagiotis suggested, but only the one with `deb.sury.org` in it.

Comment: this is strange, when I run this code from the /etc/apt directory `grep -R sury` I get no results.  Same result for `grep -R 5.5.14`.